# I want to restrict the page routing when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have made an application where I am implementing routing using react-router-dom.

So the scenario is when a user logs in, he is redirected to **localhost:3000/home** url and home page is getting rendered. When he logs out he is coming to landing page which is on **localhost:3000**.

But if the user changes the url to **localhost:3000** when logged in, everything is coming blank and he is showing as logged in, I believe this is the default behavior of routing.

The requirement is, to redirect user to home page until he is logged in even if he changes url by typing to **localhost** in the browser.

Comment: We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please edit your post to include a [mcve] so we can see what it's doing. If you need help with route protection and redirection see if this [answer](/a/66289280/8690857) helps.

Answer (score 0):

add a condition to check if the user is log in and use the Navigate from react-router-dom to redirect the user . add this in your component

```
   return (
    { ("add condition here to check if user is login") ? (
        <Navigate to="/home " />
      ) : (<div>Component body</div>)
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this if not log in then redirect to the login page and the login user then redirects to the login page.

```js
 <HashRouter>
        {!auth.token && (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
          </Routes>
        )}
        {auth.token && (
          <>
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
              </Routes>
          </>
        )}
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello your problem is easy to solve just structure your routes this way:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/login"
    render={() => {
    if (userLoggedIn) {
       return <Redirect to="/home" />;
    } 
    return <LoginPage />; 
    }}
/>
```

Or do it this way:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/home"
    render={() => {
    if (!userLoggedIn) {
       return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    } 
    return <HomePage/>; 
    }}
/>
```

I hope this helps you, if you need any other clarification please mention me in the comments below